# How to make vim high-light as python when editing scons files?

Tags: linux, vim, highlight, scons

I'm using vim to edit SConstruct files of scons, I want to make vim high-light as python grammar automatically. How to do that?

How to associate file name of 'SConstruct' with 'Python' in vimrc?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67764/seeing-scons-file-like-python-file-in-vim-file-dependent-properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your vimrc:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile SConstruct set filetype=python
```

Comment: You posted the answer as I was writing, if I realized this I would have not followed through with my post.

Comment: Probably should also do this for SConscript files.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in your .vim directory, ftdetect/sconstruct.vim.  In it, have the following command:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile SConstruct set filetype=python
```

Usually, in place of 'SConstruct' you would use a wildcard such as '*.py'; but as long as the file name is SConstruct it should work.